# Estimation of TRANS_GUESS and EMIS_GUESS matrices in Baum-Welch algorithm

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I would like to ask how do we estimate the probabilities in TRANS_GUESS and EMIS_GUESS matrices (see here http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html#f8288 ) as an input for the Baum-Welch algorithm. Should they be calculated based on the data or are they completely random? I am a little bit confused about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Should they be calculated based on the data or are they completely
>   random?

Of course based on data.

[This paper](http://people.sabanciuniv.edu/berrin/cs512/reading/rabiner-tutorial-on-hmm.pdf) by Rabiner explains how they are calculated. The answer to your question is on equations `(40a)`, `(40b)`, and `(40c)` on Pg 265. You may have to read the whole paper unto that point (9 pages) to fully udnerstand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for the paper. I took a look on it paying attention to the most related sections(training section and Choice of Model Parameters). I would say it is very "speech recognition" specific. Nevertheless, it was very helpful that you indicated the equations which are quite generic, but I am not sure about the following: how can I estimate the number of times in a specific state since I do not know which are the states as they are hidden and also I do not know which number of states will ideally fit my data. I hope my question did not confuse you.

Comment: Also here http://sifaka.cs.uiuc.edu/course/498cxz05f/hmm.pdf (Section 7) says that "Like in all other cases of applying an EM algorithm, we will start with some random guess of the parameter values".

Comment: Yes, you always begin EM with random numbers or educated guesses. But the output is trained on likelihoods based on data.

Comment: Yes, I know that the final output is based on data. Nevertheless, is always feasible to make educated guesses? For example how can I estimate the number of times in a specific state since the states are hidden?

Comment: The Baum-Welch algorithm (i.e. EM) assigns the most likely states per time point and calculates the number of times a state occurs and transitions from on state to the other based on these.